# Redirection of ports based on domain name via pf

Tags: domain-name-system, port-forwarding

We have a public facing IP on a machine (machine1) running pf firewall.
We have multiple machines behind that firewall in a lan.

On machine2 in the lan we have a service running on port 443.
To make that service available outside the lan (internet), we redirect via pf on machine1.

```
rdr on $ext_if proto tcp from any to $ext_addr port 443 -> SOMEIP port 443
```

Now I have a machine3 in the lan also having a service running on port 443.

We have domain names set up like machine2.example.com and machine3.example.com both pointing to the public facing IP on a machine1.

Is there a way to make pf "domain name aware", to sort out to which machine with service on 443 to route? Changing the ports on any machines in the lan should not be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on documentation for OpenBSD's PF fully qualified domain names are supported.

Documentation for `src_addr, dst_addr` mentions this:

> A fully qualified domain name that will be resolved via DNS when the ruleset is loaded. All resulting IP addresses will be substituted into the rule.`

Source: https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html

Answer (score 2):

While I do not think iptables is able to filter requests by domain, this sounds like perfect job for `nginx`. If you can install it on pfSense you can set it up as a proxy to other servers based on various domain/IP configuration(s). It can even act as a load-balancer if needed and you will not need to configure your firewall.

Alternatively, you can setup a separate nginx proxy server in one of the VMs. You will then have your firewall redirect all traffic to 80 and 443 ports to that VM which will then use nginx to proxy requests to specific VMs. It can also be setup on any of the existing VMs.

Comment: `pf` != `iptables`